# Sequence of for loops to access different dimensions of a tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

My problem is a bit hard to explain.

- I want to update probability distributions recursively in [0, 1]^n.
- I discretized it with 10 bins per dimension, so there are 10^n cells indexed by an n-tuple.
- Initially, I should have a uniform distribution; but then I take a threshold parameter that dictates how I propagate the distribution: every point that is "below" all the n thresholds must receive zero probability.

Here is how I hardcoded it for 1 or 3 dimensions:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

dim = 3 # or 1
bins = 10


# form the vector [10, 10, ..., 10] (n dimensions)
probabilityStarter = []
for counter in range(dim):
    probabilityStarter.append(bins)


# form the n-cube with 10^n cells
probabilityDistribution = torch.ones(probabilityStarter, dtype = torch.int8)
zeroProbability = torch.ones(probabilityStarter, dtype = torch.int8)


# if lower than the threshold, I want to zero the probability
threshold = 0.5


# for 1 dim, I just need to re-arrange, skewing the probabilities "to the right"
if dim == 1:
    for j in range(bins):
        step = (j + 0.5) / bins
        if step < threshold:
            probabilityDistribution[j] = 0
    
    probabilityDistribution = probabilityDistribution.float()
    probabilityDistribution = probabilityDistribution / torch.sum(probabilityDistribution)


# for n dim, I need to do n for loops and update the d-th dimension [:, ..., d, :, ..., :]
elif dim == 3:
    for j in range(bins):
        step = (j + 0.5) / bins
        if step > threshold:
            zeroProbability[j, :, :] = 0 # for dim 1

    for j in range(bins):
        step = (j + 0.5) / bins
        if step > threshold:
            zeroProbability[:, j, :] = 0 # for dim 2

    for j in range(bins):
        step = (j + 0.5) / bins
        if step > threshold:
            zeroProbability[:, :, j] = 0 # for dim 3

    probabilityDistribution = probabilityDistribution - zeroProbability
    probabilityDistribution = probabilityDistribution.float()
    probabilityDistribution = probabilityDistribution / torch.sum(probabilityDistribution)
```

However, if I want the 'dim' to be dynamic, how could I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the function `slice` can help us here:

```
import numpy as np
import torch

dim = 3
bins = 10

# form the vector [10, 10, ..., 10] (n dimensions)
probabilityStarter = []
for counter in range(dim):
    probabilityStarter.append(bins)

# form the n-cube with 10^n cells
probabilityDistribution = torch.ones(probabilityStarter, dtype = torch.int8)
zeroProbability = torch.ones(probabilityStarter, dtype = torch.int8)

threshold = 0.5

for d in range(dim):
    for j in range(bins):
        step = (j+0.5) / bins
        if step < threshold:
            # dynamic slicing
            selector = [slice(None)]*dim
            selector[d] = j
            selector = tuple(selector)
            probabilityDistribution[selector] = 0

probabilityDistribution = probabilityDistribution - zeroProbability
probabilityDistribution = probabilityDistribution.float()
probabilityDistribution = probabilityDistribution/torch.sum(probabilityDistribution)
```